# Find in R elements in same text vector that contain two substrings

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a text vector with five elements named **text2**. It is a sample of an actual dataset with over 1,800 rows and multiple columns.

I have reviewed other code solutions in stackoverflow and could not find a match.

**Input**

```
text2 <- c("Ian Desmond hits an inside-the-park home run (8) on a line drive down the right-field line. Brendan Rodgers scores. Tony Wolters scores." , "Ian Desmond lines out sharply to center fielder Jason Heyward.", "Ian Desmond hits a grand slam (9) to right center field. Charlie Blackmon scores. Trevor Story scores. David Dahl scores.", "Ian Desmond homers (12) on a fly ball to center field. Daniel Murphy scores.", "Wild pitch by pitcher Jake Faria. Sam Hilliard scores.")
```

**Output**
I want to know which elements in text2 contain both "Wild pitch" and "scores." I would like both the count and the element numbers. For example,
in text2 only one element (the last one) is a match. Thus, the output would contain both the count (1) and the element number (5).

**Code tried**
`str_detect(text2, ("Wild pitch|scores"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, however `str_detect(text2, ("Wild pitch|scores"))` gives you whether Wild pitch **OR** scores are contained in `text2`. This gives you your desired output:

```
ind <- str_detect(text2, "Wild pitch") & str_detect(text2, "scores")
count <- sum(ind)
count 
# 1
pos <- which(ind)
pos 
# 5
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-line dplyr solution

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

text2 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(WP = str_detect(text2,"Wild pitch"),
         S = str_detect(text2,"scores")) %>% 
  summarise(count=sum(WP==T & S==T),
            position=list(which(WP==T & S==T))) %>% 
  unnest(cols=c(position))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  count position
  <int>    <int>
1     1        5
```

Comment: when I ran your code I got this error: Error in unnest(., cols = c(position)) : could not find function "unnest"

Comment: It's because it's in the `tidyr` package, i edited my post ;)

Comment: In `summarise(count=sum(WP==T & S==T)` where are the values of 'T' coming from? What are WP and S being made equal to?

Comment: T means TRUE, so that `count=sum(WP==T & S==T)` sums the number of elements when a sentence has `"Wild pitch"` and `"scores"` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pattern` :

```
pattern <- 'Wild pitch.*scores|scores.*Wild pitch'
```

To find position, you can use `grep`

```
grep(pattern, text2)
#[1] 5
```

For count you can get the `length` of `grep` :

```
length(grep(pattern, text2))
#Can also use grepl with sum
#sum(grepl(pattern, text2))
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution with positive lookahead:

```
res <- c(length(grep("(?=Wild pitch).*scores", text2, perl = T)), 
         grep("(?=Wild pitch).*scores", text2, perl = T))

res
[1] 1 5
```

If the order of co-occurrence of `Wild pitch`and `scores`is variable, then use this pattern:

```
"(?=Wild pitch)*(?=scores).*"
```